# istio how to configure to ignore re-try on custom grpc error

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, istio

Basically i have an rest api which calls an grpc server regulaly and here the response wont send because if the record is not there grpc server will send an error saying `Error: 2 UNKNOWN: record not found` (im totally happy to change this error if it could lead to better solution)

what i want to do is only in this specific case if the `record is not found` i do not want to re-try and keep handling my request

im looking for any type of solution or like a configuration I can do tho prevent this basically I want to stop my rest-api request from hannging if the resource doesnt exist on grpc server i just want it to ignore